# ClassNotFoundException not reported in crashlytics

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, crashlytics

I noticed a huge difference in the number of crashes reported by Crashlytics (Fabric) and Google Play Developer Console. Also we are using Firebase, it also shows a number similar to Crashlytics. However, there is a huge difference in developer console.

This led me to investigate all the crash report details one by one. Then I found a specific crash which happened many many times. This crash is reported only in developer console. However, it does not exist in Crashlytics and Firebase. Developer console provides a short stacktrace of the exception. Here it is.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5196)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4799)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4683)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1389)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5181)
```

As you can see, it doesn't tell me which class is not found in the stacktrace. So my hands are tied a little bit here.

Might this crash be happening before the singleton application class is instantiated? Might be happening before Crashlytics and Firebase instances are created?

By the way, this exception is happening only in Android 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4 according to the developer console reports.

Anybody ever experienced this issue, or any ideas? Thanks in advance.